# How to pass both query string and model object as parameter to view method in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model, controller

I want to pass both model object and query string to the view so in controller action method I am creating anonymous object and passing both model object and query string as parameter to view method as shown below.

But my view is not displaying. Instead it displays my custom error page.

How to achieve this? Seems I am doing something wrong. I am pretty new to MVC. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DBInteraction db = new DBInteraction();
        EducationInfo1 obj = new EducationInfo1();
        obj = db.retrieveEducationInfo1();

        return View("EducationInfo1",new {_obj = obj , mode ="edit",docid= "1"});
    }
```

[Image of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Q7E.png)

Comment: I tried to improve formatting and capitalization (for easier reading), and fixed the image link

Comment: Create a view model and use that.

Comment: thanks but that would pass view model to view but i want to pass querystring as seperate parameters and also want to show querystring in url